# Is there a way to run multiple jobs in single pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have already configured multiple jobs in my Jenkins. For example: let say i have A,B and C jobs configured in my Jenkins. Now i have to run these three jobs manually every time. I want to run a single job which run all these three jobs (A,B,C). Is there a way to achieve this in pipeline job? please advise

Comment: This is exactly the purpose of a pipeline. What is exactly your problem then ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel i do understand that. But when i have say 10 - 20 jobs, i cannot go run all jobs manually. So this saves lot of time. Please note this is still running the jobs individually by aggregating them.

Comment: I mean, pipeline are meant for this kind of problem. So I don't understand your question as the solution simply use a normal pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can run all three jobs within a single pipeline. Here a short pipeline example we use so the user can choose which sub-job should run (default all checkboxes are checked):

```
node {
    properties([
            buildDiscarder(
                    logRotator(
                            artifactDaysToKeepStr: '',
                            artifactNumToKeepStr: '10',
                            daysToKeepStr: '',
                            numToKeepStr: '10')
            ),
            parameters([
                    booleanParam(defaultValue: true,
                            description: 'Select true to include run of Job A',
                            name: 'JOBA'),
                    booleanParam(defaultValue: true,
                            description: 'Select true to include run of Job B.',
                            name: 'JOBB'),
                    booleanParam(defaultValue: true,
                            description: 'Select true to include run of Job C',
                            name: 'JOBC')
            ])
    ])


    try {


        if (params.JOBA == true) {
            stage('Run job A') {
                build job: 'PATHTOJOBA', propagate: true, wait: true
            }
        }

        if (params.JOBB == true) {
            stage('Run job B') {
                build job: 'PATHTOJOBB', propagate: true, wait: true
            }
        }

        if (params.JOBC == true) {
            stage('Run job C') {
                build job: 'PATHTOJOBC', propagate: true, wait: true
            }
        }
--------
```

The `PATHTOJOB` is the fullname of the job you want to run. Generate a script using `<yourJenkinsHost>/pipeline-syntax/` and use `Sample step` > `build: Build a job` to identify if your path to your job is correct + it generates parameters which can be passed to that job if that is configured.

Read more [documentation here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/). If all three jobs can run independently it's advised to run your jobs in parallel to save time.